# Why Does This Animation Last So Little Time?

Tags: manim

Here is my code,

```
self.play(AnimationGroup(
        Write(quadSolution[0]),
        Write(quadSolution[1]),
        Write(quadSolution[2]),
        Write(quadSolution[3]),
        Write(quadSolution[4]),
        Write(quadSolution[5]),
        Write(quadSolution[6]),
        Write(quadSolution[7]),
        Write(quadSolution[8]),
        Write(quadSolution[9]),
        lag_ratio = 1
        ), 
        AnimationGroup(
        Animation(Mobject(), run_time = 4),
        Write(text2),
        run_time = 4,
        lag_ratio = 6
        )
        )
```

I don't know any better ways to do that list of animations, I would be thankful if anyone could tell me how to do that, but what I really want to know is why the Write(text2) doesn't have a run time of 4 seconds as it should, but instead has a run time of around a second. I don't know what is wrong with what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

You might have already found the answer you were looking for. But I think the solution to your problem would be to place the **run_time** parameter within the Write.

So it should look something like **Write(text2, run_time=4)**. I hope this helps.